Prayogas amd abhichara along with protection rites of tantric form of Rama
Do any of u happen to know about abhichara and pratyangira prayogas of tantric upasana of Lord Rama?....any pancharatra texts and their quoatationas on this except for Agastya samhita? Not much is known about tantrik upasana of Rama in pancharatra at compared to that of deities like  Narasimha and Mahasudarshana.

Sharadatilaka Tantra deals with prayogas of Rama mantra. However, abhichara karma with Vaishnava mantras is usually not done.

It definitely is done.....by many sri vaishnavas....there are severak severe abhichara prayogas of narasimha, hanuman, mahasudarshana, garuda, badabanala ram etc.

The prayogas of the deities you mentioned are not abhichara per se. Those prayogas are classified as shatkarma (marana, vashikarana, stambhana, ucchatana, vidveshana & akarshana). These prayogas are defensive in nature & are expected to be applied only against sinners. Abhichara isn't defensive & can be used to target the innocent too. It includes activities like causing diseases, paralyzing the body, creating natural calamnities, employing semi-divine beings to harass the enemy & death of a large number of people etc etc.

I know.....there are mantras of shatkarmas used in offensive nature in the first place using vaishnava deities and their mantras
